# How to safely unwrap an optional when filtering

Tags: ios, swift, swift-optionals

Currently I have a snippet of code that uses a bam operator but it needs to be unwrapped:

```
 if let tagIds = location.tagIds, !filterSet.matchesTags(tagIds as! [String]) {
            return false
        }
```

I tried using a guard:

```
  guard  let tagIds = location.tagIds, let tapgIdsString = tagIds as? [String] else {return}, !filterSet.matchesTags(tapgIdsString) {
            return false
        }
```

but it causes an error, "non-void function should return a value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to answer without knowing how everything is declared, but it sounds like you could say

```
if let tagIds = location.tagIds as? [String], !filterSet.matchesTags(tagIds)
```

Comment: Yay! I was kind of guessing. :)